# Case-insensitive search using Hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, select, case-sensitive

I'm using Hibernate for ORM of my Java app to an Oracle database (not that the database vendor matters, we may switch to another database one day), and I want to retrieve objects from the database according to user-provided strings. For example, when searching for people, if the user is looking for people who live in 'fran', I want to be able to give her people in San Francisco.

SQL is not my strong suit, and I prefer Hibernate's `Criteria` building code to hard-coded strings as it is. Can anyone point me in the right direction about how to do this in code, and if impossible, how the hard-coded SQL should look like?

Thanks,

Yuval =8-)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

For the simple case you describe, look at Restrictions.ilike(), which does a case-insensitive search.

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Person.class);
crit.add(Restrictions.ilike('town', '%fran%');
List results = crit.list();
```

Comment: Thanks... wasn't aware ilike existed in Hibernate =8-)

Comment: And for anyone looking for the NHibernate equivalent try 'InsensitiveLike()'

Comment: I just tried this out. and it does not behave case-insensitively

Comment: Hm... Prefer MatchMode.ANYWHERE over '%'

Comment: Just beware if you're switching from Eq to Like, you'll also get wildcards enabled, so things like underscores in oracle matching any character.

Comment: It won't work if you use hibernate in version below 4.1.2. There was a bug https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/commit/ff394e4a6a13a11bb1f4d6844433c2309d6bc083 and if you can't update hibernate version you can use workaround Restrictions.ilike(String, Object, MatchMode)

Answer (score 38):

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Person.class);
crit.add(Restrictions.ilike('town', 'fran', MatchMode.ANYWHERE);
List results = crit.list();
```

Comment: what is the use of MatchMode.ANYWHERE? it will match the pattern anywhere in the string. but will it give case insensitive search as well. (like if i search for lion - will it show result for Lion as well)

Answer (score 9):

If you use Spring's HibernateTemplate to interact with Hibernate, here is how you would do a case insensitive search on a user's email address:

```
getHibernateTemplate().find("from User where upper(email)=?", emailAddr.toUpperCase());
```

Comment: This comment really helped, In my application I have code as follows: `User u = new User();
        u.setUsername(username); List<User> list = HibernateTemplate.findByExample(<u>)`  to find the user from the database. But this is taking the username in the case i am giving it. But i wanted to write a query that perform case insensitive search so i used the find as shown by SamS as follows:`List<User> list = HibernateTemplate.find("from User where upper(username)=?", u.getUsername().toUpperCase());`

Answer (score 4):

The usual approach to ignoring case is to convert both the database values and the input value to upper or lower case - the resultant sql would have something like

```
select f.name from f where TO_UPPER(f.name) like '%FRAN%'
```

In hibernate criteria restrictions.like(...).ignoreCase()

I'm more familiar with Nhibernate so the syntax might not be 100% accurate

for some more info see [pro hibernate 3 extract](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=AM1Od544ei0C&pg=PA136&lpg=PA136&dq=restrictions.like+case+insensitive&source=web&ots=5xx49wOSoS&sig=sgNywi0_xScHaAeRnySueLVU_x0&hl=en&sa=X&oi=book_result&resnum=4&ct=result) and [hibernate docs 15.2. Narrowing the result set](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/reference/en/html/querycriteria-narrowing.html)

Comment: For hibernate version 3.6.1 the section for narrowing the result set is 17.2. [Link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria-narrowing)

Comment: Sir, both links are not valid.

Answer (score 4):

You also do not have to put in the '%' wildcards.  You can pass [MatchMode](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/MatchMode.html) ([docs for previous releases here](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/criterion/MatchMode.html)) in to tell the search how to behave.  `START`, `ANYWHERE`, `EXACT`, and `END` matches are the options.

Answer (score 2):

@Query(value = "FROM User u WHERE UPPER(u.email) LIKE UPPER(?1)")
List findByEmailIgnoreCase(final String email);

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done using the criterion Example, in the org.hibernate.criterion package.

```
public List findLike(Object entity, MatchMode matchMode) {
    Example example = Example.create(entity);
    example.enableLike(matchMode);
    example.ignoreCase();
    return getSession().createCriteria(entity.getClass()).add(
            example).list();
}
```

Just another way that I find useful to accomplish the above.

Answer (score 1):

Since  Hibernate 5.2 `session.createCriteria` is deprecated. Below is solution using JPA 2 CriteriaBuilder. It uses `like` and `upper`:

```
    CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Person> criteria = builder.createQuery(Person.class);
    Root<Person> root = criteria.from(Person.class);

    Expression<String> upper = builder.upper(root.get("town"));
    criteria.where(builder.like(upper, "%FRAN%"));

    session.createQuery(criteria.select(root)).getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Most default database collations are not case-sensitive, but in the SQL Server world it can be set at the instance, the database, and the column level.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using Compass a wrapper above lucene.

http://www.compass-project.org/

By adding a few annotations to your domain objects you get achieve this kind of thing.

Compass provides a simple API for working with Lucene. If you know how to use an ORM, then you will feel right at home with Compass with simple operations for save, and delete & query.

From the site itself.
"Building on top of Lucene, Compass simplifies common usage patterns of Lucene such as google-style search, index updates as well as more advanced concepts such as caching and index sharding (sub indexes). Compass also uses built in optimizations for concurrent commits and merges."

I have used this in the past and I find it great.