# Java Hibernate / Spring, doing partial match query ("contains")?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, hql

I'm still fairly new to hibernate and can't seem to find how to do this, maybe I'm searching using the wrong terminology. I am passing in a user provided value from my UI, in the example below this is the variable `testvalue`. It is for doing a search so if what the user enters is contained anywhere in an entry `e.filenametxt` I want it to return that row as a match.

For example, `testvalue = "file1"`, I would want it to be able to find a row where `e.filenametxt = "file1/someotherinfo/"`

```
String SQL_QUERY = "from EdrmTest e where e.filenametxt is :foreignkeytest ";
Query query = session.createQuery(SQL_QUERY);
query.setParameter("foreignkeytest", testvalue);
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: As a complement to the answers I'd like to mention that there is something called hibernate search that uses lucene under the covers. It resolves the same problem, but is way more powerful and scalable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
String SQL_QUERY = "from EdrmTest e where e.filenametxt LIKE :foreignkeytest ";
Query query = session.createQuery(SQL_QUERY);
query.setParameter("foreignkeytest", "%" + testvalue + "%");\
```

Try that.  The wild cards need to be in the variable (for some reason).

Comment: +1 thanks for pointing out that the "%" need to be in the parameter this isn't clear from any of the documentation I've read and I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use [the Criteria API](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/querycriteria.html) to set these types of clauses programatically; sometimes it can be much nicer to handle queries with this API as opposed to a HQL/String based query if you need to add any sort of dynamic logic (i.e. include certain clauses based on a condition).

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(EdrmTest.class); //the persistent class goes here
crit.add( Restrictions.like("filenametxt", testvalue + "%") );
//execute the query:
List<EdrmTest> results = (List<EdrmTest>) crit.list();
```

Comment: Also works, less textual, more programmatic, but definitely works.

Comment: If you want case-insensitive and you want to match anywhere, then see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120588/case-insensitive-search-using-hibernate